# Reading data from text file and forming a table using php

Tags: php, html-table, text-files

I have a text file that contains data that looks like being formatted in a table. But they are just ordered lines of text made to resemble a table. I am trying to read the text file, get only some of data and form a HTML table.

The text file looks like :

```
Class 1:
S.No RollNumber Name RandomAllocatedNumber Overall Result
---- ---------- ---- --------------------- --------------
1 ABC-BYT-M56-8T Sam Jackson NBV26173GHS Pass
2 BNS-SUD-H72-7Y Mario Javi  HAS12824SAD Pass

Class 2:
S.No RollNumber Name RandomAllocatedNumber Overall Result
---- ---------- ---- --------------------- --------------
1 POW-AVE-S36-7C Matt Stepson GSA22343GFS Pass
2 EWG-JAS-T12-3R Taylor Xavier  EWF54524EAD Pass
```

I used this code to read the complete file and display the output:

```
<?php
foreach(glob(somefile.txt") as $filename) {
$file = $filename;
$contents = file($file);
$string = implode("<br>",$contents);
echo $string;
echo "<br></br>";
}
?>
```

But I need to get only Student number, roll number and RandomAllocatedNumber from the above data.

Which would look something like:

```
ClassNo |RollNumber     |RandomAllocatedNumber

1       |ABC-BYT-M56-8T |NBV26173GHS
1       |BNS-SUD-H72-7Y |HAS12824SAD
2       |POW-AVE-S36-7C |GSA22343GFS
2       |EWG-JAS-T12-3R |EWF54524EAD
```

The above table is what I look to be displayed in the php page rather than totally reading the lines and displaying the whole file.

How can I change my simple code to get this?

Comment: I suggest researching `fgets()`, which will give you a line-by-line way to parse the file. Then you can `explode()` it with spaces and have all your parts neatly in an array for you to display in a table.

Comment: Maintaining the connection between the class number, rollnumber and the randomallocatednumber is what I actually have trouble with.

Comment: The `ClassNo` will remain the same until you come across a new one in the file, correct? So, once reading in that line from the file, `$data['ClassNo'] = ???`, until you hit the next one (outside of the loop where you read actual student info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that input format, this should produce the output you asked for:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("somefile.txt",'r');
$class = 0;
while (!feof($file))
{
    $line = trim(fgets($file));
    if ($line)
    {
        if (strlen($line)==8 && substr($line, 0, 5)=="Class") $class = $line[6];
        elseif (is_numeric($line[0]))
        {
            $parts = explode(" ",$line);
            echo $class." | ".$parts[1]." | ".$parts[count($parts)-2]."<br>";
        }
    }
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well here is what you can do.. Its my own creation

```
function mydata($file_path,$start_line=0,$end_line=0)
{
$urldatafile = file($file_path) or die("Sorry, Couldn't load data!!");
if($end_line==0){
    $linecount = count($urldatafile);
    $end_line = $linecount;
}
$array_data = array_slice($urldatafile, $start_line, $end_line);
    echo "<table>";
    foreach ($array_data as $data)
    { 
    $data = explode("===", $data);

    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$data[0]}</td><td>{$data[1]}</td><td>{$data[2]}</td><td>{$data[3]}</td>";
    echo "</tr>"
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

In example.txt file write each new line with the following data values

```
Data1===data2===data3===data4
Data1===data2===data3===data4
Data1===data2===data3===data4
Data1===data2===data3===data4
Data1===data2===data3===data4
```

USAGE:

```
mydata("PATH TO EXAMPLE TEXT FILE");
```

Please note === it separates the two values in one line, also note that in text file new line should be new line not word wrapping..

Comment: Also if you want that to start with line 10 you can use mydata("PATH TO EXAMPLE TEXT FILE",8,10); it will show results for 8th,9th and 10th row