# How to format output data from PHP form in separate text file?

Tags: php, forms, format

I've created a PHP form that outputs the form data entries into a separate text file. The problem with the output is that it's plain text with no line breaks or spaces between entries. I would like to know how I can format the output data so that it is more legible (possibly using a table or just simple line breaks).

I asked my professor for a solution and he referred me to [this page.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554310/reading-data-from-text-file-and-forming-a-table-using-php) I'm sure this is what I am looking for but I have trouble forming it for my needs. What do I need to change from the code on that page in order for it to work for me? I've tried adding and subtracting code but that resulted in syntax errors.

Here's the PHP form code:

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = '';
$emailErr = '';
$commentErr = '';
$likesErr = '';
$howErr = '';
$rateErr = '';
$name = '';
$email = '';
$comment = '';
$likes = '';
$how = '';
$rate = '';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
 $nameErr = "Name is required";
} else {
 $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
}

$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
$emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
}

if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
$commentErr = "Comments are required";
} else {
$comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["likes"])) {
$likesErr = "Things you liked is required";
} else {
$likes = test_input($_POST["likes"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["how"])) {
$howErr = "How you got to our site is required";
} else {
$how = test_input($_POST["how"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["rate"])) {
$rateErr = "Rating our site is required";
} else {
$rate = test_input($_POST["rate"]);
}
}

function resetForm($form) {
$form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
$form.find('input:radio, input:checkbox')
 .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}

function file_write($data, $feedback){
    if(is_string($data)){
        return file_put_contents($feedback, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);//this appends the new data to the file and locks it while doing so to prevent multiple access to thje file at the same time.
    }//return an error message if the data isnt a string
}

$data = $name.$email.$comment.$likes.$how.$rate.
'';
file_write($data, 'feedback.php')

?>
```

**EDIT 1:**
This is the section that I believe is causing the issues since there are two `file_write`:

```
function file_write($data, $feedback){
    if(is_string($data)){
        return file_put_contents($feedback, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }//return an error message if the data isnt a string
}


$data = $name.PHP_EOL.$email.PHP_EOL.$comment.PHP_EOL.$likes.PHP_EOL.$how.PHP_EOL.$rate.‌PHP_EOL.
file_write($data, 'feedback.php');
```

Comment: What would be your expected output? Also have you tried to implement the code from the link into your current code?

Comment: Just to have the entries on separate lines so that one can read the feedback easily. I have tried to implement the code from the link in to my current code but I received nothing but syntax errors. I tried to implement it 5 different ways but it resulted in only syntax errors. I believe it was due to the fact that code was for that user's specific problem and it wasn't for mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of this answer, I am assuming that `file_write` is a function that you've included somewhere. AFAIK `file_write` isn't a standard PHP function for writing to a file.

Your data is written to the file as a single line with no spaces because you haven't specified any spaces or line breaks.

If you want line breaks in-between each of the fields, do the following:

```
$data = $name.PHP_EOL.$email.PHP_EOL.$comment.PHP_EOL.$likes.PHP_EOL.$how.PHP_EOL.$rate;
file_write($data, 'feedback.php');
```

It is best to use `PHP_EOL` for adding line breaks. It is cross-platform -- PHP will automatically choose the correct newline character(s) for whichever platform your code is running on.

Comment: Hooray, progress! So now the entries in the text file have spaces between them but they are still on the same line. I thought the "PHP_EOL" would produce line breaks between the entries in a single submission so they'll be on separate lines? Also, when a second submission is made it is on the same line and has no space between itself and the last data submission. How would I go about creating two line breaks to separate different submissions? Sorry that I'm having this information spoon fed to me, I'm only a few weeks in to coding. Thank you for your support and patience.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code for your `file_write` function. Using the normal methods, writing to a file with `PHP_EOL` inserted would result in a new line.

Comment: To my knowledge this is a normal method for a `file_write` function. Here's the code: `function file_write($data, $feedback){
        if(is_string($data)){
            return file_put_contents($feedback, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        }//return an error message if the data isnt a string
}`

Comment: @TaylorRoy Ok, the code for `file_write` is fine. Execute this little script via php on the command line -- what is the result? `<?php
$data = "test".PHP_EOL."test2".PHP_EOL."test3";
file_put_contents("test.log", $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>`  For me, I get line breaks in the new file between each block of text.

Comment: I tried your test.log script and they were each on their own lines. So then, instead of having my data entries sent to the `feedback.php` I just used the `test.log` file and it worked! Each answer has a line break between them. Now I'm trying to figure out how to have a line break between different submissions. How may I go about this?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. Thank you SO much for your help. You sir are a true Lorax.

Answer (score 1):

Try "**\n**" or you can also try "**\r\n**"
So you can following this code:

```
    function file_write($data, $feedback){
      if(is_string($data)){
        return file_put_contents($feedback, $data.'\n\n', FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
      }//return an error message if the data isnt a string
    }

    $data = $name.'\n'.$email.'\n'.$comment.'\n'.$likes.'\n'.$how.'\n'.$rate;
```

Comment: Different operating systems's uses different line endings approaches. So I hope any from this can help.

Comment: After trying yours, the `\n` shows up on the output page. This is the result of two submissions. Here's what it looks like `\n\nplease work cmon@aol.com land Links Links from another site 1\n\nJohn Hamm johnjohn@aol.com But please man Site design Search engine 3\n\n` Not sure why this is. I'm assuming the `\n\n` is for a line break while the `\n` is just for a space?

Answer (score 1):

first comment.  Keep the FILE_APPEND flag as it will keep an on-going storage.

Second. In the future, if you want to analyze your data having it separated with newlines will be a pain to parse.  I suggest exporting comma delimited with newlines only for new entries.  You can then easily parse or import (as a csv) into Excel.

```
$data = $name.','.$email.','.$comment.','.$likes.','.$how.','.$rate.PHP_EOL;
file_write($data, 'feedback.php');
```

However, you may run into an issue where somebody puts a comma in your web form.  How do you account for that?  You could enclose each item in the row with quotes. You can do that one yourself!  good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `PHP_EOL` constant so that line endings appropriate to the server will be output, in which case your code would look like

```
$data = $_POST['name'] . PHP_EOL;
$data .= $_POST['email'] . PHP_EOL;
$data .= $_POST['comment'] . PHP_EOL;
$data .= $_POST['likes'] . PHP_EOL;
$data .= $_POST['how'] . PHP_EOL;
$data .= $_POST['rate'] . PHP_EOL;
```

OR try this one

```
$data = $_POST['name'] . "\r\n";
```

IF this not helps you try this as well

```
$data = sprintf("%s\n%s\n%s\n",$_POST['name'],$_POST['email'], $_POST['comment'],$_POST['how'],$_POST['rate']);
file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND);
```

You may try this :

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = '';
$emailErr = '';
$commentErr = '';
$likesErr = '';
$howErr = '';
$rateErr = '';
$name = '';
$email = '';
$comment = '';
$likes = '';
$how = '';
$rate = '';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
 $nameErr = "Name is required";
} else {
 $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
}

$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
$emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
}

if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
$commentErr = "Comments are required";
} else {
$comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["likes"])) {
$likesErr = "Things you liked is required";
} else {
$likes = test_input($_POST["likes"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["how"])) {
$howErr = "How you got to our site is required";
} else {
$how = test_input($_POST["how"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["rate"])) {
$rateErr = "Rating our site is required";
} else {
$rate = test_input($_POST["rate"]);
}
}

function resetForm($form) {
$form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
$form.find('input:radio, input:checkbox')
 .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}

function file_write($data, $feedback){
    if(is_string($data)){
        return file_put_contents($feedback, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);//this appends the new data to the file and locks it while doing so to prevent multiple access to thje file at the same time.
    }//return an error message if the data isnt a string
}

$data = $name.PHP_EOL;
$data .= $email.PHP_EOL;
$data .= $comment.PHP_EOL;
$data .= $likes.PHP_EOL;
$data .= $how.PHP_EOL;
$data .= $rate.PHP_EOL;

file_write($data, 'feedback.php')

?>
```

> Hope any of this help you

Comment: I tried implementing your code and for some reason the feedback page is blank. I still included the `file_write` function to so it should be writing the form entries to the text file but formatting them the way you described. Not sure why the blank page is the result...

Comment: Can you please tell me which operating system your using?

Comment: $data = $name.PHP_EOL.$email.PHP_EOL.$comment.PHP_EOL.$likes.PHP_EOL.$how.PHP_EOL.$rate.PHP_EOL.

Comment: I'm on the mac operating system.

Comment: I tried with the new code you provided and the same result, a blank page. It's odd that this is happening. It makes sense so it should be working in theory.

Comment: Kindly try new updated code. At the last I manage some changes.

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put it to the code. The page is no longer blank, hooray! The entries are separated by a space which is great but I need them to be on separate line. Do you know how I can fix this? Thanks again.

Comment: Try this in updated code : $data = $name. "\r\n"; In place of .PHP_EOL use . "\r\n"

Comment: I tried the new way you showed with the `\r\n` but it only showed the name and none of the other entries. I used the code you gave and even tried it with line breaks between them but same result unfortunately.